# How to switch Authentication from one user to another using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Firstly, I login as user X, and I have a function like:

```
public function loginAs($userId)
{
    Auth::loginUsingId($userId); // now use Y user
    return response()->json(['logged' => Auth::check(), 'user' => Auth::user()]);

}
```

and when I try to print out `Auth::check()` it returns **TRUE** which is fine so far I am logged now as user Y, the thing is that I do first login as an X user and then switch to another Y user but when I do call some other functoins it seems that the current user logged is still X, and I want to be Y the current user logged... This might have to do something with session or I dont know exactly how to do this thing, would be grateful if someone has any sample or have any idea how to achieve such things in Laravel 5.

Comment: Are you saying that after logging in with user Y, `Auth::user()` is still returning the X user? What is the result of `dump(Auth::loginUsingId($userId));`?

Comment: Did you try `Auth::logout()` before `Auth::loginUsingId($userId)`?

Comment: Try this one http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/temporary-user-switching

Comment: Did you switched user without logging out first one?

Answer (score 5):

Can you elaborate? I was able to switch users using the following:

```
use Auth;

class TempController extends Controller
{

    public function index() {
        $user = User::find(1);
        Auth::login($user);
        var_dump(Auth::user()->id); // returns 1
        Auth::logout(); 

        var_dump(Auth::user()); // returns null

        $user = User::find(2);
        Auth::login($user);
        var_dump(Auth::user()->id); // returns 2
        Auth::logout();

    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/temp', 'TempController@index');
```

If you run this, you can see the logged in user's id changes.

Comment: Good solution. You can also make it have a parameter so u can choose which account to switch too: `Route::get('debug/hopacc/{id}', 'ProfileController@debughop')->name('debug.hop');` 
`public function debughop($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect('costumer/account/edit')->with('user');
    }` edit: make sure to check if the user exists first :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use impersonating
There is a weblog post about that
http://blog.mauriziobonani.com/easily-impersonate-any-user-in-a-laravel-application/